Having trouble deploying Laravel 11 due to Composer detected issues
Current php version
PHP 8.3.6 (cli) (built: Apr 11 2024 20:23:19) (NTS) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.3.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies     with Zend OPcache v8.3.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
Issue when open the app.
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0".
composer update. its working fine . when i trying to open the web app its is giving composer detected issues in your platform.
Laravel 11
Getting the error 'Composer detected issues in your platform: laravel 11'. Tried updating Composer and clearing cache but no luck. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Are you sure the console client and the apache server are using the same PHP version?

how can i find that

please give me the brief details about that

Execute this code in your server:
<?php 
phpinfo();
it is resolved.
my configuration file php-fpm was older.I changed to latest.
